# How to cover scheduler class in test class?

Tags: unit-test

I am writing test class how to cover scheduler class in test class.

Class:

```
global class updatecontactaccount implements database.batchable<sobject>,schedulable{
    global database.querylocator start(Database.Batchablecontext BC)
    {
        string query = 'select id,name,accountnumber,(select id,lastname,accountid from contacts) from account where name = \'testaccount\'';
        return database.getquerylocator(query);
    }
     global void execute(Database.Batchablecontext BC, List<account> Scope){
        list<contact> listcon = new list<contact>();
        map<string,contact> oldmap = new map<string,contact>();
        map<string,contact> newmap = new map<string,contact>();
        account acc = [select id,name,(select id, lastname from contacts) from account where name=: 'BICS'];
            for(contact a : scope[0].contacts){
                oldmap.put(a.lastname,a);
            }
            for(contact c : acc.contacts){
                newmap.put(c.lastname,c);
            }
            for(contact c : oldmap.values()){
                if(!newmap.containskey(c.lastname))
            {
            c.accountid = acc.id;
                listcon.add(c);                                        
            }
            }
            system.debug('contact:'+listcon);
            update listcon;
    }
    global void finish(Database.Batchablecontext BC){
    }
 global void execute(schedulablecontext sc){
    updatecontactaccount up = new updatecontactaccount();
    database.executebatch(up);
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
@istest
public class Updatecontactaccount_Test {
    static testmethod void testbatch(){
        account a = new account();
        a.name = 'testaccount';
        insert a;
        contact c = new contact();
        c.lastname = 'Test';
        c.accountid = a.id;
        insert c;
        account acc = new account();
        acc.name = 'test11';
        insert acc;
        contact con = new contact();
        con.lastname = 'Test11';
        con.accountid = acc.id;
        insert con;
        updatecontactaccount up = new updatecontactaccount();
        database.executebatch(up);
     }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use Test.startTest() and Test,stopTest() to execute the batch. The job executes after the call to Test.stopTest. Any asynchronous code included within Test.startTest and Test.stopTest is executed synchronously after Test.stopTest.

```
Test.startTest();
updatecontactaccount up = new updatecontactaccount();
database.executebatch(up);
Test.stopTest();
```

Suggest you to go through [Using Batch Apex Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/asynchronous_apex/units/async_apex_batch)

Answer (score 0):

You have to schedule the job inside testStart and testStop. No matter what is the scheduled time, the job will get executed immediately once it finds test.StopTest();

You can replace

```
updatecontactaccount up = new updatecontactaccount();
database.executebatch(up);
```

with

```
Test.startTest();
String schTime = '0 0 12 * * ?';
updatecontactaccount schJob = new updatecontactaccount();
system.schedule('TestUpdateConAccJob', schTime, schJob);
Test.stopTest();
```

As you are calling the batch class from scheduled class, code coverage will cover the batch class as well.